# body cannot contain '-'

Tags: support, editing

what is this, I post some snippet and it tell me **body cannot contain`-`(after I inspect it with firebug I saw it is "_"  **, what this meaning really? we can't put a snippet with "-" in question body or this is a issue in system? -

[image]

Comment: I edited the question, and I didn't get any error. May you describe exactly which part where you trying to edit, to get that error?

Comment: @kiamlaluno it was strange for me too, Also I tried to put that code here but I faced it here too.then I go to sublime and did some all replacements ( first replace all "-" to "_" but error exists, then inspect the error and I findout it is "_" then try to replace all "_" to "-"). really is strange

Comment: So the problem you get is writing code containing `$this->userAuth`, for example.

Comment: @kiamlaluno exactly I didn't uderstand which part of my snippet cause this, the error messages was around all textarea box. maybe

Comment: In my answer, I wrote `$this->userAuth`, and I didn't get any error message. I also tried with the question, but I didn't get any error message. It could be I am not editing the correct part. Let's see what a Stack Exchange developer says about this.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thank you for time and attention

Comment: Are you using Arabic characters, by any chance? Specifically either the [Arabic full stop](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06D4/index.htm) or the [Arabic tatweel](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0640/index.htm)? That would explain the message, as all Arabic characters are blocked on the site - because it was getting a lot of Arabic spam.

Comment: @Oded I have Persian keyboard and it is possible  the reason of this error is I used "-"(this is dash in Persian keyboard) instead "-" in my question.

Comment: OK - looks like mystery solved ;)